# Asp.net - Trouble with updating LINQ Classes

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

We just created a new field in a database table, and so deleted, and re-inserted the table in the LINQ Class. The new database field appears in the LINQ Class in the diagram. However, when we're using the field, we get an error that says the table does not contain a definition for the field.

Any ideas on how we can solve this? Thanks!

**UPDATE: What steps are required to update the LINQ to SQL Class? Maybe we're doing something wrong.**

**UPDATE 2: Picture of our problem - LINQ - http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/6033/usertable.png | Code - http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/5145/linqerror.png**

Comment: There are a number of possible causes, which depend on:

Field Name (or better yet, table def)?
Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities?

Comment: The field name is a Gender shortint field. This is a Linq to SQL Class. Another trouble we're having is the designer file seems to get deleted when we delete a table and re-insert it - any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like the codegen failed - did you by any chance get a "the custom tool mslinqtosqlgenerator failed..." error when saving the dbml file after changing it? If so, check out this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/0c0f77a6-d712-43d2-a990-555df7960123

Comment: Nope - we didn't get any visible errors :[ - but I'll look into the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the entire LINQ Class, recreate it and re-add the tables for my problem to go away. Simply deleting a single table and re-adding it, or deleting all tables in the class and re-adding them did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Check the table def side of your mapping documents, either using properties in the designer, or by closing Studio and examining the XML.  I recommend the designer.

Make sure the field name matches the field name in the database.
I've had problems with a few reserved keywords when using Linq2Entities, and I'd recommend you avoid reserved words in names (even though the [] handle them).

Comment: I've done this before. also comparing them to the previous version in source control is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your question necessary, it may help to solve it - I've been a long time fan of the LINQ to SQL and Entities tools by Huagati. The re-sync aspect alone has saved me so much time, it's well worth the $50 (for the standard version) IMO.

http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Hope it helps...

***Edit:***

In order to update the LINQ to SQL classes, you can either do it manually (bllurgh) or, you can remove them from the designer and drag-and-drop them from the Data Connections node in the Server Explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for visual web developer - I emailed support.

Comment: @stringo0 - if Visual Web Developer is one of the 'express edition' versions of Visual Studio then unfortunately those don't support add-ins...   ...add-ins unfortunately require VS standard/pro/team...

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error when trying to remove the table and re-add it - our new field doesn't seem to get recognized :[ :

'dataClass.aspnet_User' does not contain a definition for 'Gender' and no extension method 'Gender' accepting a first argument of type 'dataClass.aspnet_User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the designer and re-adding it (ensuring that the field is actually available and ready on/ in the table)?

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same issue, but I found that deleting the problematic tables in the Object Relational Designer and re-adding them (and re-adding the associations as well) solved the issue. I did not have to delete the entire DataContext, nor did I have to delete any of the tables that were still working properly. I would recommend trying this first before doing anything more drastic.